# Is Etoro Halal?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, finance

They have an Islamic account as well : https://www.etoro.com/customer-service/islamic-account/

My doubt is mainly around CFDs (contract for differences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website clearly mentions the following solutions for Islamic finance.

> No interest on contracts lasting longer than 24 hours – zero rollover interest consistently.
>   eToro doesn’t take any additional rollover commissions for contracts lasting longer than 24 hours.
>   We do not charge any commissions or fees for account management. Our revenues come strictly from spreads (the difference between the buy and sell prices of an instrument).
>   An eToro Islamic account provides you with interest-free leverage.

However, the website doesn't state what kind of instruments they are selling or buying. To make it halal you should know the nature of business as well. It is unclear to answer from looking into the website, Please ask the company for more details.